# How does loc in pandas dataframe work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A newbee question, but i'm realy confused...
Suppose there is dataframe like this:

```
>>>test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,0,0],'b':[1,1,0,0]})
>>>test
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  0  0
3  0  0
```

Running the follwing code,

```
test.loc[2:] = 1
```

the data on the 3rd and 4th row would be set to 1,the dataframe would become:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
```

but if the subset is set a varable first，then dataframe would not change,

```
temp = test.loc[2:]
temp = 2 #nothing changed, just the temp variable set to 2
```

so what's the difference between these two code, why does the first one changed the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Python assigns everything by value. Every variable is a pointer to an object. You're dataframe is an object which is never copied unless you're explicitly copying it. So when you assign temp to a slice of your DataFrame, you're then resetting the value of temp to point to 2. Hence resetting the value. Try keeping it as functional/pythonic as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with loc. This is a standard way how assignment works in python. A data frame is an object. `loc` is a method in the dataframe object. Consider the example below where `a` is created as a list and `b` is a reference to `a`, when you are changing `b`, you are only making the assignment of the variable `b` to point to something else. `a` remains the same, until you change the assignment to variable `a`.

```
#create a list
a = [1,2,3]

# add another reference to the list
b = a

b[1] = 5

b
Out[4]: [1, 5, 3]

# reassign the reference
b = 3

b
Out[6]: 3

a
Out[7]: [1, 5, 3]
```